# How can I fix this Error: PHP Warning: zlib_decode(): data error in /Path?

Tags: php, web, apache2, readfile

I want to display a .log file. For this I use the file_puts_contents function of Php. I have to decode the File but it doesnt works.
Heres my Code:

```
$openFile = file_get_contents($PathToLog);
echo(zlib_decode(substr($openFile, 10, 100)));
```

Comment: What actual compression was used? Is it really a raw zlib stream? Why the odd substr call? Is it perhaps gzip-encoded after all?

Comment: @mario I will try the gzip-encoded function

Comment: if the hole file is compressed, you cannot randomly decompress parts of it... decrompress it entirely..

Comment: @LarsStegelitz So without the substr?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Works now thx